# Apache Zeppelin didn't start without any errors on windows

Tags: windows, apache-zeppelin

I just started learning Apache Zeppelin for Data Analysis, but I got an unexpected error when I was following the installation steps.

I have downloaded Apache Zeppelin all interpreter package for windows and extracted the file. And also I have followed these steps:

1. Download Java and set JAVA_HOME
2. Downloaded hadoop and set HADOOP_HOME
3. Installed Apache Spark
4. Ran zeppelin.cmd from bin folder

Here's the screenshot - Zeppelin didn't start

[image]

Did I miss something, and could someone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: did you see anything in the log directory? the *.out and the *.log

Comment: @shainnif Where can I find those files? there is no log folder. By the way, I tried to install zeppelin and spark in ubuntu and it's fine.

Comment: it should be in <INSTALL_DIR>/logs/* . have a look in common.cmd